# Who owns this bit coin address?

Tags: bitcoin

If I have a bit coin address, how do I find out user info? I see there is a http://bitcoinwhoswho.com  but I did not get any information back on my user.

Here is what the address kind of looks like (some substitutions) 6cc711d3e7c71b49304d5d8312f739d14807aa8d5eca4e98c18000ccf2e7b2d

Thanks

Comment: I think this specific question is better asked at https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/.  But for more general questions about bitcoin, anonymity and traceability there are already [several existing questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=bitcoin) on this site.

Comment: Did you try to google the address string? If the user wants to be known she would put the address on their web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can look at the transactions for every single bitcoin transaction that has ever happened, but that doesnt mean that the transactions will actually reveal the information about the wallet holder, other than their public key.

If you want to learn more about what transactions that account has been involved with, you can check out: [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/home)  or [Block Explorer](https://blockexplorer.com/).

If you want to find the personal details about the account holder, you will probably need a warrant and go knocking on the exchanges associated with the account you have in mind.

Comment: thanks- are there any places a user could store data in? Like an "about me" or "bio"

Comment: Yes, transactions allow for small annotations, but almost nobody would put in their own info.